# AWSKinesisRecorder get the records that are not streamed

Tags: ios, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

> In **AWSKinesisRecorder** ([here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSAbstractKinesisRecorder.html)), how can we check if our records are submitted to the server / reached the AWS or *check if we have records on disk that are not yet submitted*?

```
kinesisRecorder.submitAllRecords()?.continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                Logger.log(method: .error, "\(#function) \(#line) \(#file)", "Error: \(error)")
            }
            if let result = task.result {
                Logger.log(method: .info, "\(#function) \(#line) \(#file)", "Result: \(result)")
            }
            print("FINISHED AWSTask kinesisRecorder", task, task.error, task.isCompleted, task.isFaulted, task.isCancelled)
            return nil
        })
```

The completion block **never returns an error** neither does the **task.result** is also **nil**, even if the internet is turned off on the device.

Answer (score 1):

### Not Possible

Seems like there is no public API available to fetch the records that are written onto the local mobile storage, neither you can read the sent records from Kinesis.

**Its aim is to stream data in a unidirectional way.**

I had to create another API to get the details of records received on the server end and had to rely on the Kinesis that each record is 100% written safely onto the local storage. *So, far I have not seen any data loss.*